# Outlook saying its not the default client (even though it is)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-10

Whenever the user tries to open an email file, specifically when it has been put on a shared drive, it gives this error: 
"Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request. Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client".

The issue is, it is set as the default mail client, everywhere. I've gone into the outlook settings, and set it there, I've changed the default applications setting to outlook, I've reinstalled office, repaired office, changed the defaults to something else and back, etc etc. I cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was that the user had "Preview Pane" on in Windows Explorer. Took me forever to find any reference to this solution, and it worked immediately when I turned it off. Explorer tries to open the msg file in preview pane but can't.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3189902/can-t-preview-msg-files-in-windows-file-explorer-with-64-bit-outlook

Now I feel like an idiot, I must never have searched it with "msg file" in the query. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Hi Anath3ma, I'm glad to hear that you have solved it. To help more people who have the same issue to find this solution, you can mark you solution. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

> > Whenever the user tries to open an email file, specifically when it has been put on a shared drive, it gives this error: "Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request. Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client".

I found a thread about “**Microsoft Outlook 2013 not recognized as the default mail client when opening emails on shared drives**” and you can refer to it:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d130977a-d637-4dfa-ab67-5d3cea9c67b0/microsoft-outlook-2013-not-recognized-as-the-default-mail-client-when-opening-emails-on-shared?forum=exchangesvrclients

Hope it helpful!

Best regards,

Ivan Wang

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.